# relationshipName - Parent child relationship dynamic query

Tags: soql, standard-objects

I'm trying to get relationshipName for standard childobject to build dynamic query. 
Is there any function that returns the queryable name of the standard sObject for SOQL query. Example : Contact->Contacts // ActivityHistory -> ActivityHistories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DescribeFieldResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) class `getRelationshipName()` method to dynamically obtain relationship name for any lookup field (standard or custom).

Answer (score -1):

Have a play with the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), particularly the functionality under the info tab. You can see fields, relationships and also use the Queries tab to prepare and try out SOQL and SOSL.

[image]